# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tier_price_1.percentage_value' error before magento migration

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration

I am done my magento migration but then I show one error while indexing : unknow collum percentage_value
And error is

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tier_price_1.percentage_value'
>   in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index
>   _price_temp` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `pw`.`website_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_tax_class_id.valu e, tad_tax_class_id.value) AS `tax_class_id`,
>   IFNULL((ta_price.value), 0) AS `price`, IFNULL((LEAST(ta_price.value,
>   IF(ta_special_price.value IS NOT  NULL AND
>   (IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_ special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <=
>   cwd.website_date) AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_da te.value_id, -1) >
>   0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_spec
>   ial_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= cwd.website_date),
>   ta_special_price.value, ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL
>   AND tier_p rice_2.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL
>   AND tier_price_4.value_id is NULL, NULL,
>   LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0, ROUND(ta_ price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_pri
>   ce_2.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))),  ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_
>   3.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 10 0), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0)))), ~0))), 0) AS `final_price`, IFNULL((LEAST(ta_price.value,
>   IF(ta_special_price.value IS NOT  NULL AND
>   (IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas
>   _special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= cwd.website_date) AND
>   (IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_d ate.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_spe
>   cial_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= cwd.website_date),
>   ta_special_price.value, ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL
>   AND tier_ price_2.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL
>   AND tier_price_4.value_id is NULL, NULL,
>   LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0, ROUND(ta
>   _price.value * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_pr ice_2.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))) , ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price
>   _3.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 1 00), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0)))), ~0))), 0) AS `min_price`, IFNULL((LEAST(ta_price.value,
>   IF(ta_special_price.value IS NOT  NULL AND
>   (IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_ special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <=
>   cwd.website_date) AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_da te.value_id, -1) >
>   0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_spec
>   ial_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= cwd.website_date),
>   ta_special_price.value, ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL
>   AND tier_p rice_2.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL
>   AND tier_price_4.value_id is NULL, NULL,
>   LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0, ROUND(ta_ price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_pri
>   ce_2.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))),  ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_
>   3.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 10 0), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0)))), ~0))), 0) AS `max_price`, IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL AND
>   tier_price_2.value_id is NU LL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL AND
>   tier_price_4.value_id is NULL, NULL,
>   LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   RO UND(tier_price_1.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_2.value = 0, ROUND (ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier
>   _price_3.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_price_3.value * cwd.rate, 4 ))), ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0, ROUND(ta_price.value * (1 -
>   ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value * cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4),
>   ROUND(tier_pr ice_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))), ~0))) AS `tier_price` FROM
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>   CROSS JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg`
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id =
>   e.entity_id
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON pw.website_id =
>   cwd.website_id
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id =
>   e.entity_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id AND
>   tp.website_id  = pw.website_id
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_1` ON
>   tier_price_1.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_1.all_groups = 0
>   AND tier_pri ce_1.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id AND
>   tier_price_1.qty = 1 AND tier_price_1.website_id = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_2` ON
>   tier_price_2.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_2.all_groups = 0
>   AND tier_pri ce_2.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id AND
>   tier_price_2.qty = 1 AND tier_price_2.website_id = pw.website_id
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_3` ON
>   tier_price_3.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_3.all_groups = 1
>   AND tier_pri ce_3.customer_group_id = 0 AND tier_price_3.qty = 1 AND
>   tier_price_3.website_id = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_4` ON
>   tier_price_4.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_4.all_groups = 1
>   AND tier_pri ce_4.customer_group_id = 0 AND tier_price_4.qty = 1 AND
>   tier_price_4.website_id = pw.website_id
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON
>   tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 129 AND  tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON
>   tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 129 AND  tas_tax_class_id.store_id =
>   cwd.default_store_id
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON
>   tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 94
>   AND tad_status.store_ id = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON
>   tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 94
>   AND tas_status.store_i d = cwd.default_store_id
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_price` ON
>   ta_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price.attribute_id = 74 AND
>   ta_price.store_id =  0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_special_price` ON
>   ta_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   ta_special_price.attribute_id = 75  AND ta_special_price.store_id = 0 
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date`
>   ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_special_from_date.at tribute_id = 76 AND
>   tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date`
>   ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_special_from_date.at tribute_id = 76 AND
>   tas_special_from_date.store_id = cwd.default_store_id
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date`
>   ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_special_to_date.attribut e_id = 77 AND
>   tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date`
>   ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_special_to_date.attribut e_id = 77 AND
>   tas_special_to_date.store_id = cwd.default_store_id WHERE
>   (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value,
>   tad_status.value) 
>   = 1) AND (e.type_id = 'simple') AND (e.entity_id BETWEEN 3 AND 2593)

Comment: what are your migration versions?

Comment: Magento 1 to Magento 2.3.0

Comment: Solved : Just add percentage_value (decimale - 12,4) in catalog_product_entity_tier_price table

Comment: Krunal, can you put this as an answer to close the post?

Comment: Sorry @brentwpeterson but I am not able to give the answer